# Dynamic v-for loop in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have to yml files (one in **Fr** and another in **Nl**), each with a line called "language", with the respective language.

Let's say that I'm receiving from the back a list in both languages of words, I save them as **listFr** & **listNl**.

And what I want to do is a dynamic v-for loop, using the variable language mentioned above, maybe something like this

```
         <ul>
          <li
            v-for="(list, index) in `list${$t('language')}`"
            :key="index"
          >
            <p class="element-title">{{ list.title }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

But obviously this is not correct as it's not showing the list of words.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way

```html
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(list, index) in dynamicList" :key="index">
            <p class="element-title">{{ list.title }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            listFr: [],
            listNi: [],
        }
    },
    computed: {
        dynamicList() {
            return this["list" + this.$t('language')]
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use index as the key tho.